# My react client using Signalr socket triggers send function when another react client is refreshed

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr, eventtrigger

When I log into my React application with another client and any client is refreshed, the other client also triggers the signalr send function, how is this possible?

The windows on the client side act as if it's one socket and trigger the sending data function of the other, I couldn't find a solution for this problem, I'm curious about your opinions.

my connect code is as follows;

```
 const connection = new signalr
        .HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(url, {
            skipNegotiation: true,
            transport: 1,
        })
        .withHubProtocol(new signalRMsgPack.MessagePackHubProtocol()) 
        .withAutomaticReconnect([]) 
        .build();
```

client function that sends data to socket triggered by other client;

```
function layoutPositionHandler(account) {
    let binaryAccount = msgpack.encode(account);
    ConnectionAlgo.send("PrePositions", binaryAccount);
}
```